# rails, tests, and fixtures - Error "underlying cause no such file to load"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fixtures

I'm trying to get the tests for my rails app to run, but it keeps giving me the following errors:

`Unable to load tp_approval_step, underlying cause no such file to load -- tp_approval_step`

I have a fixture named tp_approval_step.yml and I have also added this to my test_helper.rb

```
set_fixture_class :tp_approval_step => ApprovalProcessStep
```

I am receiving these errors for all of my fixtures. Any ideas about what I can do to eliminate these errors?

Thanks

Comment: Some other thoughts - 
Does this have something to do with pluralization? One of my fixtures is tp_process, but it is claiming that it cannot load file for tp_proces with one S instead of two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short - after browsing and asking on rubyonrails-talk - almost nobody uses or cares about fixtures. The prevailing wisdom in the community is to use a factory class to load the database. There are libraries that can help with this, in particular, factory_girl and machinist.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my test.  I had accidentally added a comma to the line above the "def setup".  Once I removed that comma the yaml loaded and the tests worked. Example below, note the comma after :testing_dog.

```
 attr_accessor  :public_api_client, :testing_dog,

  ##############################
  #
  ##############################
  def setup
.....
```